# How AnnotationSessionFactoryBean and SessionFactory are of the same type?

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection

In a typical Hibernate Spring application, we configure  AnnotationSessionFactoryBean something like following:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
        p:packagesToScan="com.company.model"
        p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties" />
```

Now we can inject `SessionFactory` in our DAOs:

```
@Autowired org.hibernate.SessionFactory ssessionFactory;
```

That means  `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` and  `ssessionFactory` are of the same type, that implies they should have superclass subclass relationship. But I can't find such relationship from the API docs. What  am I missing? How they are of the same type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they aren't of the same type. [`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html) is a [`FactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html). This is a special interface managed by Spring which produces a bean of some type. `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` produces a `SessionFactory`.